# AWS EB Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a django webapp into AWS EB. The app works fine in the localhost but when I try to deploy it, I keep getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'.

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'
```

django.config

```
option_settings:
 aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: myapp.wsgi:application

packages:
  yum:
    mod_ssl: []
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My local directory looks like this:

```
my_project
├── .ebextensions
├── myapp
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── requirement.txt
.
.
.
```

I am using Amazon Linux 2 with the Python environment. How can I make it work?